# How to minimize process time of the procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-performance, insert-update

I created such a quite complex stored procedure that checks the password from `c_sent_messages` table if exists in `c_passwords` table. Then it's entering some messages and updating records from the database. Finally it is entering the record from `c_sent_messages` to `archive` table. Everything was good before i add the two rows which add record to the `archive` and delete the message from `c_sent_messages` (to not inflate storage)

```
INSERT INTO archive SELECT *, NOW() FROM c_sent_messages WHERE id=idi;          
DELETE FROM c_sent_messages WHERE  id=idi;
```

My processor is also a good one(Intel 7700 HQ) and i am not running any other software/process.
After i added these two rows, the procedure took too many time to add records to `archive`  table. I want to minimize process time of this procedure. Is there any way to make it faster? (Adding 1000 records to the `archive` took 120 seconds)

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE flood () 
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare ifExist int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE numara VARCHAR(10);
    declare adamin_gonderdigi varchar(150);
  declare idi int default 0;


    myloop: LOOP




      SET idi               = (SELECT id  from c_sent_messages where stats = 'N' limit 1);
        SET numara            = (SELECT sender  from c_sent_messages where id = idi);
        SET adamin_gonderdigi = (SELECT msg_text from c_sent_messages WHERE id = idi);

      select count(1) into ifExist from c_passwords b WHERE adamin_gonderdigi = b.pass;

        IF ifExist > 0 THEN
            set ifExist = 0;
                select count(1) into ifExist from c_sent_messages a WHERE a.stats ="N";
                IF ifExist > 0 THEN
                    INSERT INTO c_received_messages ( receiver, sender, msg_text, stats, x_date )
                        VALUES
                            (numara, "5757", "Code is received successfully.", "S",NOW());
                    UPDATE c_passwords a SET a.stats = "S", a.x_date = NOW()
                    WHERE pass = adamin_gonderdigi;         

                        update c_sent_messages set stats = 'S' where id = idi;

                ELSE

                    INSERT INTO c_received_messages ( receiver, sender, msg_text, stats, x_date )
                    VALUES(numara,"5757","Code is used before!","S",NOW());

                    update c_sent_messages set stats = 'U' where id = idi;

                END IF; 

        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO c_received_messages  ( receiver, sender, msg_text, stats, x_date )
            VALUES(numara,"5757","Please send a valid code!","S",NOW());

            update c_sent_messages set stats = 'F' where id = idi;
        END IF;     

        INSERT INTO archive SELECT *, NOW() FROM c_sent_messages WHERE id = idi;            
        DELETE FROM c_sent_messages WHERE  id=idi;

    SET i = i + 1;
        IF
            i = 900000 THEN
                LEAVE myloop;

        END IF;     
    END LOOP myloop;

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Do you have an index on the column id in table c_sent_messages? If not, try creating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The 3 SELECTs at the start of the loop can be done with a single `SELECT` -- see `JOIN`.
- Do you have `INDEX(stats, id)`?
- See if IODKU can replace your select/if/insert/update sequence.
- Try to do the entire procedure in a single SQL statement without looping 900000 times.